# EMACS, MacOS Sierra, and Mission Control work badly together

Tags: osx

Since upgrading to MacOS a/k/a OS/X 10.12, I've noticed an annoying behavior. I have several spaces open. If I use [CMD][TAB] to move to EMACS from another program, the display switches to EMACS, it becomes visible, but then is immediately sent to the back and another application comes up. If I [CMD][TAB] *again*, it brings EMACS to the front.

I have no idea if this is an EMACS issue or a MacOX issue, but it's annoying and I'd appreciate any suggestions to make it stop.

I'm using

```
GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1404.47) of 2016-09-08
```

and

```
System Version: macOS 10.12.1 (16B2555)
```

Comment: It may be helpful to specify where it is that you obtained your Emacs version, or how it is that you built it from source.  It might be worth a try to see if the generic pre-built tried and true Emacs from https://emacsformacosx.com/ suffers from the same issues.

Comment: this is the brew emacs-mac version

Answer (score 1):

I am currently digging into some changed/different behaviour with respect to frames, macOS windows and mission control, but I'm not seeing the problem you mention. Not sure yet if my issues are a sign of a problem or a sign of something needing to be re-configured.

I appear to be using the same maOS version as you and my emacs is build from homebrew using the 'brew install emacs' recipe. Version details are

```
GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0, NS appkit-1504.60 Version 10.12.1 (Build 16B2555))
```

Note the differences between our versions. Perhaps try a re-build? The brew command I used is

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa --with-gnutls --srgb --with-librsvg --with-ns
```

I'm going to give the 'brew cask install emacs' recipe a go to see if that makes a difference for my issue

Comment: I just removed the 'standard' homebrew emacs i.e. brew install emacs' with the
cask based version which uses the pkg version from the emacsformac.com
site. While it seems to be working fine, I still see some odd behaviour when
creating new frames when in fullscreen mode. More investigation needed. However,
switching between tabs with cmd+tab seems to be working fine (as well as it did
with the other build), so can't reproduce the issue you are seeing.

Comment: the version I was using was built with `brew install emacs-mac` from Yamamoto. https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac/

Comment: I'm building a version as you did right now.